# Detecting the language of a text from a crawled website in Python

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I wrote several different spiders for different websites that output the text of articles and the URLs. Example:

```
import scrapy
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("german"))


class FruehstueckSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "fruestueckerinnen"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.diefruehstueckerinnen.at/stadt/wien/',
        ]
        urls += [urls[0] + 'page/' + str(i) + '/' for i in range(1,17)]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        hrefs = response.css('div.text > a')
        yield from response.follow_all(hrefs, callback = self.parse_attr)

    def parse_attr(self, response):

        yield {
                'text': ' '.join([i for i  in word_tokenize(re.sub(pattern='[^a-zA-Z_\-ÖöÜüÄäßèé]',string=  BeautifulSoup(response.css('.content-inner.single-content').get(),"html.parser").find(class_="content-inner single-content").text , repl=' ')) if i not in stop_words and not re.match('[0-9]', i) and len(i) >1]),
                'url': response.request.url,
        }
```

I want to detect the language the whole text is written into. Does it make sense to write it under 'text' and 'url' as another property? I know that there is a function called `detect` (and the input is a string) from `langdetect`, but how do I use it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another field inside yield like this

```
from langdetect import detect  # add this to your import


# change the parse_attr function like this
def parse_attr(self, response):
    text = ' '.join([i for i  in word_tokenize(re.sub(pattern='[^a-zA-Z_\-ÖöÜüÄäßèé]',string=  BeautifulSoup(response.css('.content-inner.single-content').get(),"html.parser").find(class_="content-inner single-content").text , repl=' ')) if i not in stop_words and not re.match('[0-9]', i) and len(i) >1])
    language = detect(text)

    yield {
            'text': text,
            'language': language,
            'url': response.request.url,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "lang"-attribute a html attribute that should define the language of a page. I suggest that you use this as a reference for the site because it is the most direct way to recognize this attribute. This attribute was defined to help for example voice software to choose the right language for the pronunciation.

```html
 <html lang="en">
...
</html>
```

Adding the language to the output is a matter of taste. It doesn't hurt but do you really need it? You can always include but not use the value everywhere.

Comment: So if I do it for every spider, how do I output it? For example in the spider that I gave as an example? I was thinking that I could use the detect function and actually iterate through every text output from every spider, but that seems more complicated.

Comment: requesthandler=request.css,  htmltag=str(str(requesthandler.html).replace("<html","" )).replace("",">"). You should assign the bs4 object that is returned to a new object and then you can retrieve the html tag and directly strip it.  But replace requesthandler=request.css by a more appropriate way.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that sometimes the language at the beginning of the page source doesn't correspond to the language of the texts, for example here: https://www.wearevienna.com/. The language is set to English but the texts are in German.